# Php button click

Tags: php

I am new to php and I am confused with the following problem:
I have a button called BtnAdd wich is surrounded with a form tag(POST)

Now I am trying to do +1 with each click. This is my code:

```
$counter = 0;

if (isset($_POST['BtnAdd'])) 
{ 
 $counter++;
}

echo $counter
```

My problem is that each time I click the button it only returns 1 but it never goes up

If you have any idea please post.

Comment: Are you sure this is the code you're using ? Your code should either return 0 or 3. And please don't forget `;`

Comment: Could you please post a more complete version of your code? The example you provided should be obviously working, that way.

Comment: I am sorry, my mistake! the problem is that the counter doesn't goes up each time I click on the button

Answer (score 3):

You need to store the reference to "3" somewhere, it is not a magic number and I presume it's not going to be hard coded in. Your current logic flow is this

- click button on form
- script processing form assigns variable to **zero**
- script increments `$counter` **if** the button data exists, from **zero** to **one**

What you should be doing is replacing `$counter` with a number read from somewhere (session, file, database).

Here are some storage options for it:

- **Session**: easy to use, easy to update, easy to read, but will only last until the browser is closed. Tutorial: http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_sessions.asp
- **Flat file:** relatively easy to use, relies on file and folder permissions, doesn't need a database. Tutorial: http://www.webdesign.org/web-programming/php/easy-flat-file-hit-counter.9887.html
- **Database**: relatively easy to use, should be used if you need to store this number after a browser window is closed. Tutorial: https://defuse.ca/php-hit-counter.htm

Here's a quick example of how to do it with sessions:

```
<?php

session_start();

if(!isset($_SESSION['counter']))
    $_SESSION['counter'] = 0; // create variable if doesn't exist

if(isset($_POST['BtnAdd'])) {
    $_SESSION['counter']++;
}

echo $_SESSION['counter'];

?>
```

- this will at least increment your counter while your browser window is still open.

Answer (score 0):

when you are submitting the form, in the processing page before the counter, you are initialising the counter to the value 0 everytime you post.your counter value is not getting stored anywhere.you have to store the present value so that incrment it next time

```
session_start();
$counter = 0;
if(isset($_SESSION['count'])){
    $counter=$_SESSION['count'];
}


if (isset($_POST['BtnAdd'])) 
{ 
   $counter++;
   $_SESSION['count']=$counter;
}

echo $counter
```

here it is stored in session and u can access stored count value from session